# Transformation to avoid division by 0

Tags: transformation, epsilon-delta

I want to model the relationship between a discrete variable $A$ with values in the range $[-5,5]$ and a continuous variable $B$ as $\dfrac A  B$.

How do I transform the data to avoid dividing by $0$? I read that one way is to add a small variable epsilon to both variables?

Comment: I don't see how this could be of any help. If B'= B + epsilon, As soon as B takes the value -epsilon, you will have B'= 0 again... Or perhaps I did not understand the question.

Comment: @Martigan I agree, that's a problem, although unlikely. Would like to see if there other solutions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you want to modify $B$ when it comes close to $0$.

In gnuplot I could do it like this

> eps = 0.1
>
> b(x) = abs(x) < eps  ? eps : x

where I defined it to be constant $\epsilon \gt 0$ close to $0$.

[image: fear of the null]

That means of course that you have at least "arithmetic if" available in your function specification language.

Comment: Why $abs(x) < eps$? Isn't $x=0$ sufficient?

Comment: Oh I see. Double comparison precision issue?

Comment: Yes, $\mbox{abs}(x - 0) < \mbox{eps} = 10^{-5}$ would mean $x$ is about  zero (considering 5 digits precision).

Comment: I was wondering if there was a transformation that completely shifts the plane away from 0 but I guess that's just not possible since we can't predict the values of x and y.

Comment: I fear I would need more background info, to come up with something elegant. That $A/B$ will give large values for small $B$.

Comment: The two indicators are conflicting, meaning when they both increase the resulting ratio should be lower than when they are going in opposite directions. Thus in addition to address the division by 0 I also need to figure the opposite signs case. For example, for $A=5$ and $B=-10$, I expect a high ratio. It sounds like a common case, calculating the ratio for two variable having both negative domains, including 0?